# POST Request (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, post

How do you make a simple POST request in Javascript without using a forms and without posting back?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype

Comment: this is too vague, and you could get started via google query

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript post request like a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: [In my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692196/post-request-javascript/25423688#25423688) you **can do a request invisible to the user without AJAX, popups or refresh the page**. Of course, you don't retrieve a response but it's usefull for **RESTFul** API without AJAX.

Answer (score 34):

Though I am taking the code sample from @sundeep answer, but posting the code here for completeness

```
var url = "sample-url.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=alpha";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.send(params);
```

Comment: So simple, I love it :D

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using AJAX calls (XMLHttpRequest object)

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: I think if he wanted to use AJAX he would have used. In my answer I have made a post request **without `AJAX`** and without open a page, popup or refresh the page :).

Answer (score 3):

I have made a function that sends a request **without refreshing the page**, without opening a page, and **without AJAX**. The process is invisible to the user. I use a false iframe to send a request:

```
/**
* Make a request without Ajax and without refreshing the page
* Invisible for the user
* @param url string
* @param params object
* @param method string get or post
**/
function requestWithoutAjax( url, params, method ){
    
    params = params || {};
    method = method || "post";

    // function to remove the iframe
    var removeIframe = function( iframe ){
        iframe.parentElement.removeChild(iframe);
    };
    
    //Make an iframe...
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    
    iframe.onload = function(){
        var iframeDoc = this.contentWindow.document;
        
        // Make a invisible form
        var form = iframeDoc.createElement('form');
        form.method = method;
        form.action = url;
        iframeDoc.body.appendChild(form);
        
        // pass the parameters
        for( var name in params ){
            var input = iframeDoc.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'hidden';
            input.name = name;
            input.value = params[name];
            form.appendChild(input);
        }
        
        form.submit();
        //Remove the iframe
        setTimeout( function(){ 
            removeIframe(iframe);
        }, 500);
    };
    
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Now you can do it:

```
requestWithoutAjax('url/to', { id: 2, price: 2.5, lastname: 'Gamez'});
```

See how works!: http://jsfiddle.net/b87pzbye/10/.

Comment: EDIT: seems somebody figured out how to make a working version which doesn't raise a potential XSS attack flag. http://jsfiddle.net/b87pzbye/37/

Comment: "_without open[ing] a page_" You're opening a page in an iframe.

Comment: @Geremia I appreciate the clarification and understand your perspective. The iframe does indeed load a page, but it's done in a way that's invisible and non-disruptive to the user, aligning with the function's intent.