# One Php Submit Button have to open two php pages instead of only one

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing right now an php project. I want to do two actions with only one submit button, the button have to open two php pages.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use javascript to do that

Answer (score 0):

"Opening" pages is done by your browser - not by your php scripts. Therefore you need to do this on the client side. The most obvious way to achive this is with javascript.
You can open a new tab/window by javascript as explained here:

[JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

If this new page needs some data from your form too, you can send the form data as URL-Parameters (GET-request). Or as POST-request which is a bit more tricky with pure javascript:

[POST Request (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692196/post-request-javascript)

By using jQuery this will be much easier:

[jQuery post request (not AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583703/jquery-post-request-not-ajax)